# android game doesn't execute on phone being used as adb

Tags: android, libgdx

I am a new aspirant in the android game development. I have **open-JDK-8** on my Linux and use my phone in **debugging mode** for testing my game. But when I go running it, it installs but doesn't open, rather just shows that the

> app unfortunately has stopped working

what is the reason of the problem and how do I fix it? I must say that I have followed the codes from many **YouTube tutorials** themselves, so if their code runs, mine should too! kindly help me out.

```
the logcat in adb says the following-
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 29761
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.kotr.game, PID: 10360
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime: java.util.EmptyStackException
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:57)
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.kotr.game.States.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:39)
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.kotr.game.kotr.render(kotr.java:34)
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1590)
09-15 02:59:41.415 10360 10432 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1286)
```

kindly tell me what u can make out of that!

Answer (score 1):

If `GameStateManager` is a class in your code, then your stacktrace says at line 39, you're trying to view a non-existing item at the top of an empty `Stack`. Check if the `Stack` is empty before doing `peek()`.

Comment: i have given the log in the edited question, please reply